# Method vs Functions Usage golang

Tags: go

I know differences between func and method. But I am confusing for usages between:

```
prod:=Product{"title","brand","model"}
prod.Add()
```

or:

```
prod:=Product{"title","brand","model"}
products.Add(&prod) // products is package
```

Comment: I don't know why this is down voted so much, but i see it as a perfectly valid question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are two distinct cases, one which is a **method** belongs to `Product` instance and one is a **global function** belongs to `products` package.

```
type Product struct {
        Title string
        Brand string
        Model string
}

// This method add value to a field in Product
func (p *Product) Add(field, value string) {
        switch field {
        case "Title":
                p.Title = value
        case "Brand":
                p.Brand = value
        case "Model":
                p.Model = value
        }
}
```

The above provide a method to add value to itself as an instance of `Product`, i.e.

```
product1 := &Product{}
product1.Add("Title", "first_title")
```

The second case is a public function exposed from a `product` package. In this case, an instance (or a pointer) of a `Product` must be supplied as an argument.

```
package products

func Add(p *Product, field, value string) {
        // Same switch-case as above
}
```

`Add` function then can be used from any other package.

```
package main

import (
        "path/to/products"
)

type Product struct {
        // ...
}

func main() {
        product1 := &Product{}
        products.Add(product1, "Title", "first_title")
```

Normally in your scenario, the first approach is preferred since it encapsulates the functionality of managing its attributes to itself.

The second scenario might be seen as a "class method approach" (for those coming from OOP like Python or Java) where the package is similar to class and the exposed functions similar to class methods which are more generic and can be used across many types which implement the same interface, like so:

```
package products

// where p is a Product interface
func Add(p Product, field, value string) {
        // Same switch-case as above
}

type Product interface {
        someMethod()
}
```

And from another package:

```
package main

import (
        "path/to/products"
)

type Car struct {
        Title string
        Brand string
        Model string
}

type Ship struct {
        // ...
}

type Airplane struct {
        // ...
}

// All types implement `Product` and can be used in `products.Add`
func (c *Car) someMethod() {}
func (s *Ship) someMethod() {}
func (a *Airplane) someMethod() {}

func main() {
       plane := &Airplane{}
       products.Add(plane, "Model", "Boeing-747")
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for detailed explanation!

Answer (score 2):

This is expected as per the spec:

> The type of a method is the type of a function with the receiver as first argument.

See https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_declarations

So when you declare the `Add` method on `Product`, you get a function that accepts a pointer to a `Product` as its first argument. So you end up with

```
func (p *Product) Add()
```

being translated to

```
func Add(p *Product)
```

So both your calls are valid and end up doing the same

Answer (score 0):

Extending the fantastic answer by @Danilo:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type T struct {
    i int
}

func (t *T) F() {
    t = &T{1}
    fmt.Println(t.i)
}

func F(t *T) {
    fmt.Println(t.i)
}

func main() {
    t := T{2}
    (&t).F()
    F(&t)
}
```

The type of the method `func (t *T) F()` is the type of the function `func F(t *T)` with the receiver `(t *T)` as first argument.